# Simple c code with sleep gives no output after execution

Tags: c, sleep

I wrote the following piece of code to simulate a callback. But this got stuck and not even prints "inside main". I tried this on my unix machine and also on online compiler but same behavior. Have I missed anything ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void sleep_50sec()
{
    printf("inside sleep_50sec");

    sleep(50);

}

int main()
{
    int i;
    printf("inside main");
    sleep(1);

    for( i =0; i < 100;i++)
    {   printf("Loop %d",i);
        sleep_50sec();
    }
return 0;
}
```

Output

```
root@xyz> ./a.out
```

Comment: Does the execution complete or does it hang?

Comment: `printf` is flushed to `stdout` when it sees a newline character `\n`. Append that to your `printf` calls and you should see some printouts.

Comment: @yano assuming you don't inherit a `stdout` set to `_IOFBF`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `\n` when printing to `stdout`.

```
printf("inside main\n");
```

The reason a `\n` is needed is because `printf` flushes data to `stdout` after `\n` was reached.

You can print to `stderr` to see your data immediately, without using `\n`:

```
fprintf(stderr, "test");
```

By the way, when calling `printf()` output will be written to `stdout`. So `printf(...)` is the same as `fprintf(stdout, ...)`

Comment: with *some* explanation, this could be a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to flush the `stdout`. It can be done by the `'\n'` character inside the format string or by the [`fflush`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) command:

```
void sleep_50sec() {
    printf("inside sleep_50sec");
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(50);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not seeing anything printed is because the `crt` (C runtime) buffers your outputs and will only output to the screen after K characters have been accumulated. One solution will be to use '\n' - this hints `crt` that a complete line has been written, and that it *should* print it to the screen. Another solution will be to implicitly flush `stdout` like in my example below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void sleep_50sec()
{
    printf("inside sleep_50sec");
    fflush(stdout);

    sleep(50);

}

int main()
{
    int i;
    printf("inside main");
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);

    for( i =0; i < 100;i++)
    {   printf("Loop %d",i);
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep_50sec();
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's your C runtime that controls the buffering.

Comment: @FelixPalmen correct, fixed

Comment: @IshayPeled How do you "flush" the CRT? I think you mean `stdout` and that is explicit flushing not implicit flushing.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Of course you're right (: corrected